# Move mail item from one folder to another folder

Tags: delphi, email, delphi-2010, indy10

How to move mail from one mailbox(user folder) to another mailbox (user folder) in a same mail account.Our mail server supports IMAP and POP3 protocal.I am using Delphi 2010

Answer (score 2):

Only the IMAP protocol can move messages around between folders.  Indy does have a `TIdIMAP4` component for that.

However, the IMAP protocol does not define a single command to move a message.  You would have to first COPY the message to the desired mailbox (use `TIdIMAP4.CopyMsg()` or `TIdIMAP4.UIDCopyMsg()` method), then DELETE the original message (use the `TIdIMAP4.DeleteMsgs()` or `TIdIMAP4.UIDDeleteMsg()` method, followed by the `TIdIMAP4.ExpungeMailBox()` method when ready).